# Show that for reals $>0$ $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ : $a_1a_2...a_n < 1 \iff$ $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ $\geq 2$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt[k]{a_i} < n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Show that for any positive reals $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ we have $a_1a_2...a_n < 1 \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, k\geq 2$ for which $\sqrt[k]{a_1} + \sqrt[k]{a_2} + ... + \sqrt[k]{a_n} < n$.

The $\Leftarrow$ part is very easy (just apply AM-GM for that $k$). I wasn't able to solve the other part.

It's enough to show that if $\sqrt[k]{a_1} + \sqrt[k]{a_2} + ... + \sqrt[k]{a_n} \geq n$ for any $k$, then $a_1a_2...a_n \geq 1$. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to show that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{\sqrt[k]{a_1}+\ldots+\sqrt[k]{a_n}}{n} \right)^k = \sqrt[n]{a_1\ldots a_n}.$

Comment: That sounds very nice. Well, I'm thinking about using the squeeze theorem: clearly $\frac{\sqrt[k]{a_1} + \sqrt[k]{a_2} + ... + \sqrt[k]{a_n}}{n} \geq \sqrt[kn]{a_1a_2...a_n}$. However, I don't know how to get the other part of the squeeze theorem...

Comment: Sorry for suggesting not so easy way to prove the problem. Instead, you can try to prove the following easy lemma: if $x,y$ are both $>1$ or both $<1$ then $1+xy>x+y$. Then, using the lemma, you should be able to reduce the problem to the case $n=2$.